# What is the best way to display number of screens in iPhone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm a beginner. I want to do a sample app. In that I want to display 100 questions one by one each. If the user answers first question and he clicks next then I have to display another question. In this way I have to display 100 questions. The only way I know is taking 100 views.

Can you guys give me any best solution.  And another doubt is how to display multiple answers randomly.

Comment: I once thought that computer games like gothic had every possible screen state drawn by some designer and I felt terrible sorry for him and imagined how long he had to sit in some room and draw every picture, every state, etc. Just remembered this while reading your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to do just load the question by only calling the viewDidload method at the next button click event.

you have to just take one

int count;

increment at the next button click event and from that count value you just load the question.

you can also use the arc4random function for generating the random number.

int r = arc4random() % 100;

Answer (score 0):

You can use Random() for displaying the random answer which is the inbuilt function of the iOS